# Div creation and styling not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a number of divs and iterate through them on click.
The iteration only works on every other click.
Strangely, I'm getting no errors.
I tried moving the `divs` variable declaration outside of the for loop.

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  let div = document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="div">${i}</div>`)
  let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
  divs[i].style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
  divs[i].onclick = () => {
    close(divs[i])
    open(divs[i + 1])
  }
}

function randomColor() {
  let e = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  return `#${e}`;
}

function close(t) {
  t.style.transform = 'scale(0.5)'
  t.style.opacity = '0'
  setTimeout(function() {
    t.style.display = 'none'
  }, 500)
}

function open(t) {
  t.style.display = 'block'
  setTimeout(function() {
    t.style.transform = 'scale(1)'
    t.style.opacity = '1'
  }, 5)
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

Comment: Where does exactly that `for` loop is at? Maybe it is being triggered by some on click event itself?

Comment: The `for` loop is not wrapped inside a click event, it probably isn't being triggered from a click

Comment: Hmm.. the code looks fine to me

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with `open(divs[i + 1])`?

Comment: Ahh found it... Why this line is inside the `for` loop?? `let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('div');` I think it should be before the loop

Comment: I moved it outside of the for loop and it still doesn't work

Comment: Actually you don't need `divs` at all because the intention is to create a new div and add on click event to it right? So if I add the new div with id like `<div id="new-${i}" class="div">${i}</div>` and access is by `getElementById("new-"+i)` then wouldn't it be more efficient?

Comment: Ok, i'll try that, thanks

Comment: I think the error is on the `open(document.getElementById(\`div-${i + 1}\`))`, because when I removed it it worked

Comment: Then I suggest you don't pass anything in `open()` and `close()` and use `this.style` to change the clicked element directly without relying on parameter `t`

Comment: Just change this `close(divs[i])` into `close(this)` and this
   `open(divs[i + 1])` into `open(this)` if you want minimum change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to

- `open(divs[(i + 1) % 6])` so it loop correctly
- hide all divs at initial (except one)

there still some minor issue with the initial state (need to add `opacity` and `transform`, I leave it for simplicity), I think you should use proper class instead of inline css to make it easier.

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  let div = document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 
         `<div class="div" style="display:${i==0?'block':'none'}">${i}</div>`
      )
}

let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  divs[i].style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
  divs[i].onclick = () => {
    close(divs[i])
    open(divs[(i + 1) % 6])
  }
}

function randomColor() {
  let e = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  return `#${e}`;
}

function close(t) {
  t.style.transform = 'scale(0.5)'
  t.style.opacity = '0'
  setTimeout(function() {
    t.style.display = 'none'
  }, 500)
}

function open(t) {
  t.style.display = 'block'
  setTimeout(function() {
    t.style.transform = 'scale(1)'
    t.style.opacity = '1'
  }, 5)
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```